# Can you make a sacrifice for dark gods in d&d 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, magic, character-advancement, religions-and-deities

*Ok so here is the story.*

We are currently having a campaign of neutral/evil characters, we take what we want and of of course there are always consequences of our actions.

We have acquired a *deck of many things* (it was destroyed soon after) and the homebrew version of the card called "idiot" reduced my character to 4 Intelligence (before he had 10).

We also got an ability score increase, so I used it to raise my characters Intelligence to 6 but still the character is dumb as hell. With the gold we made he bought an *intelligence potion* that is rising it by 1d4 +1 for one hour (also homebrew). Still I do not wish the character to stay like this forever. He and the party have a plan to destroy a small city and sacrifice the citizens in the name of some dark power (god, demon) to reverse the effect of the card.

**What do you think about this idea, and could it work based on your knowledge? Would you allow it?**

Info - we are playing in a world made by the GM based on Faerun, but not identical.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Orwell, take the [tour] when you have a moment. This question appears to be an opinion poll, we don’t really handle this sort of question here. It may be better suited for a traditional discussion forum, see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for our curated list.

Comment: In particular, "could it work based on your knowledge" is unanswerable, since you are asking us to understand the homebrew rules for your GM's campaign, which we do not.  "What do you think about this idea?" and "Would you allow it?" are explicitly opinion-based questions, which we don't do here.  You **could** ask something like, "RAW, what options are there to remove the Int loss caused by a cursed item?" or "What are some effects produced by ritual sacrifices within official products?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Only your DM can tell you if this can work

The world is their own, homebrew world. What you are asking for therefore cannot be answered with published materials about Faerun.

Neither is something like this covered in the rules, this is purely a story-driven solution, that needs fiat and acceptance by your DM. There is no spell or magic item or class ability in the rules that would allow you to improve ability scores by sacrificing victims to an evil power.